# Number of common zeros of two quadratic polynomials in ${\Bbb C}[t,x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory

The following theorem is in Artin's *Algebra*(2nd edition):

> **Theorem 11.9.10** Two nonzero polynomials $f(t,x)$ and $g(t,x)$ in two variables have only finitely many common zeros in ${\Bbb C}^2$, unless they have a common nonconstant factor in ${\Bbb C}[t,x]$.

A comment after this theorem says that "*It is harder to prove the Bezout bound than the finiteness. We won't need that bound, so we won't prove it*".

Then there is an exercise in the 1st edition:

> Prove that two quadratic polynomials $f, g$ in two variables have at most four common zeros, unless they have a nonconstant factor in common.

Then in the 2nd edition, this exercise has been changed to the following one:

> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be the zeros of quadratic polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively that don't have a common linear factor.
>   (a) Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct points of intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$, and let $L$ be the (complex) line through $p$ and $q$. Prove that there are constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, not both zero, so that $g=c_1f_1+c_2f_2$ vanishes identically on $L$. Prove also that $g$ is the product of linear polynomials.
>   (b)**Prove that $C_1$ and $C_2$ have at most $4$ points in common.**

I think (a) is supposed to be a hint to (b). But I don't see how I can make the implication.

I guess I have to show that there cannot be too many $(c_1,c_2)$ as in (a), while such pairs might correspond to zeros of a polynomial of small degree.

---

Here is my **question**:

How can I prove (b) using (a)?

Comment: I think the idea is to apply (a) to two pairs of intersection points (chosen appropriately). Then you get two equalities $c_1f_1+c_2f_2=g$, $d_1f_1+d_2f_2=h$ where both $g$ and $h$ are products of linear polynomials, and have no common linear factor. Then check that the common zeroes of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the same as those of $g$ and $h$. But since the latter are products of _linear_ polynomials, it is not too hard to see there are at most 4 of them. (Let me know if you would like more details.)

Comment: Dear Jack: sorry, that was a little bit terse. What I meant was: in part (a), you choose $p$ and $q$, and then find $g$ a product of linear polynomials $l_1$ and $l_2$. What I meant by "appropriately" is that you should then choose intersection points, call them $r$ and $s$, such that neither $l_1$ nor $l_2$ is zero at both $r$ and $s$.

Comment: As I see from the first comment, there are basically 3 steps: 1. get $(c_1,c_2)$ and $(d_1,d_2)$ such that $g$ and $h$ have no common linear factor; 2. $V(g,h)=V(f_1,f_2)$; 3. There are at most 4 linear polynomials in $g$ and $h$. But I'm not able to follow your reasoning: 1. how such $g$ and $h$ exist? 2. $V(f_1,f_2)⊂V(g,h)$ is obviously true, but how about $V(g,h)⊂V(f_1,f_2)$? 3. what is the relation between (2) and (3) and how does (3) imply that $|C_1∩C_2|≤4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the discussion in the comments is getting a little confusing, so let me write a full answer instead. I'll try to spell everything out in detail.

We are assuming statement (a) and trying to deduce (b). Of course, we can assume that $C_1 \cap C_2$ contains at least 4 points.

**Claim 1**: No 3 points of $C_1 \cap C_2$ lie on a line.

*Proof of claim*: A nonzero quadratic polynomial in one variable has at most 2 roots. If 3 points $p,q,r$ of $C_1 \cap C_2$ lay on a line $L$, then both $f_1$ and $f_2$ would be identically zero on $L$. But then they would have a linear factor in common, contrary to hypothesis. $\ \square$

Let $p,q$ be two points of $C_1 \cap C_2$, and let $L_1 =\overline{pq}$,
By Part (a) we can find numbers $c_1, \ c_2$ such that $g_1=c_1f_1+c_2f_2$  vanishes on $L_1$ and factors into linear polynomials, say $g_1=l_1 \lambda_1$, where $l_1$ vanishes on $L_1$.

Now choose $r$ to be a point of $C_1 \cap C_2$ such that neither $l_1$ or $\lambda_1$ vanishes on $\overline{pr}$. (If $\lambda_1$ doesn't vanish at $p$, any point other than $p$ or $q$ will do; if it does, then by Claim 1 $V(l_1) \cup V(\lambda_1)$ contains at most 3 points of $C_1 \cap C_2$, so we can take $r$ to be any other point of $C_1 \cap C_2$.)

Let $L_2=\overline{pr}$; then applying (a) again we can find numbers $d_1, \ d_2$ such that $g_2=d_1f_1+d_2f_2$  vanishes on $L_2$ and factors into linear polynomials.

**Claim 2:** The matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
c_1 & c_2 \\
d_1 & d_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
is invertible.

*Proof of claim:* From Part (a) both rows of the matrix are nonzero. Suppose there exists $\lambda$ such that $(\lambda d_1, \lambda d_2)=(c_1,c_2)$. Then $g_1=\lambda g_2$. But then $g_1$ must vanish on $L_2$, contrary to the choice of $L_2$. $\ \square$

So now we can write 
$$\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
g_1 \\ g_2 
\end{pmatrix} &=
M \begin{pmatrix}
f_1 \\ f_2 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$
for an *invertible* matrix $M$. This shows that $V(f_1,f_2)=V(g_1,g_2)$; moreover, it also shows that $g_1$ and $g_2$ cannot share a linear factor, since then $f_1$ and $f_2$ would also, contrary to hypothesis.

So we can write $g_1=l_1 \lambda_1$, $g_2= l_2\lambda_2$ where the $l_i$ and $\lambda_i$ are linear polynomials, and no linear term appears in both factorisations.

So now 
$$V(f_1,f_2) = V(g_1,g_2) = \bigcup_{i,j=1,2} V(l_i) \cap V(\lambda_j).$$

Each of the intersections consists of at most 1 point, so the union consists of at most 4 points.

Comment: Fair enough. This is very helpful. Thank you! (In "$l_1\cup\lambda_1$ contains at most 3 points of $C_1\cap C_2$…", I think you mean "$V(l_1)\cup V(\lambda_1)$ contains at most…")

Comment: Dear Jack, thanks for spotting that typo. I fixed it.